# compare aggregates with row data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySql related to purchase of Inventory.

The table format is as below :

- itemname  (varchar)
- vendor    (varchar)
- pdate     (datetime)
- qty  (decimal)
- rate (decimal)
- total (decimal)
- id (mediumint) (autoincrement)

```
A report is to be generated that must have the following columns

Item     HighestRate     HighestRateDate        LowestRate      LowestRateDate    % difference

--
Item  is the itemname
HighestRate and HighestRateDate are rates at maximum
LowestRate and Date are rates at minimum
%difference is a basic difference percentage between highestrate and lowestrate of a row
```

I have prepared the following query

```
SELECT itemname,rate,pdate  from purchases 
group by itemname
having rate = max(rate)
order by itemname
```

which does generate one half of the report.

However since it requires both the lowest and highest rate. This report is incomplete and printing two reports makes comparison difficult.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thankyou

Comment: Make subquery of your statement, duplicate it (change `MAX` to `MIN`) and do an `INNER JOIN` on both subquery over `itemname`

Comment: And what if maximum (or mininum) appears in two dates or more?

Comment: @ypercube IIRC mysql is lenient on these matters and picks one at random.

Comment: @ypercube is your question related to me?

Comment: @rabudde: Not to you, to the OP.

Comment: @Srisa: That was my question. If a random one is wanted or all. Different queries needed for different needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need an index on `(itemname, rate)` for this query not to be awfully slow.

If there are two or more dates with same maximum (or minimum) rate, then a (more or less) random date will be selected. If you want to control that, change the `ORDER BY rate ASC` (to `ORDER BY rate ASC, pdate DESC` for example):

```
SELECT 
    di.itemname  AS Item
  , maxr.rate    AS HighestRate
  , maxr.pdate   AS HighestRateDate
  , minr.rate    AS LowestRate
  , minr.pdate   AS LowestRateDate
  , (maxr.rate - minr.rate)/maxr.rate        --- calculations
                 AS PrecentDifference
FROM
    ( SELECT DISTINCT itemname
      FROM purchases 
    ) AS di
  JOIN
    purchases AS minr
      ON  minr.id =                          --- I guess this is the PK
          ( SELECT id
            FROM purchases p
            WHERE p.itemname = di.itemname 
            ORDER BY rate ASC
            LIMIT 1
          )
  JOIN 
    purchases AS maxr
      ON  maxr.id =                      
          ( SELECT id
            FROM purchases p
            WHERE p.itemname = di.itemname 
            ORDER BY rate DESC
            LIMIT 1
          )
```

Comment: brilliant answer, this is exactly what the report is about. it saved not only calculation time, but also the number of pages in volumes that would have been printed (so in a way you saved some trees as well ;-)

Comment: the report runs fine on a small sample. I will check on realtime data which is around  a million rows. (i have suggested a new index to be created).

Comment: I have used the query in another report to add daterange and show transaction ID as follows ----- SELECT di.itemname AS Item , minr.rate AS LowestRate , minr.pdate AS LowestRateDate , minr.ID as LowestRateID FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT itemname FROM purchases where pdate between '2011/10/1' AND '2011/10/31' ) AS di JOIN purchases AS minr ON minr.id = ( SELECT id FROM purchases p WHERE p.itemname = di.itemname ORDER BY rate ASC LIMIT 1 ).   Will the same changes apply to the above query without any performance overhead ?

Comment: thanx again, my desk is clear now and i am good for the weekend.

Comment: @arvind: You'll have to put the extra conditions in the subqueries too: `WHERE p.itemname = di.itemname AND pdate BETWEEN '2011-10-01' AND '2011-10-31'`

Comment: Yes, just updated the query. ------ SELECT      di.itemname  AS Item   , minr.rate AS LowestRate   
, minr.pdate   AS LowestRateDate  , minr.ID as LowestRateID
FROM  ( SELECT DISTINCT itemname FROM purchases where pdate between '2011/10/1' AND '2011/10/31') AS di   
JOIN purchases AS minr ON  minr.id = 
( SELECT id FROM purchases p  WHERE p.itemname = di.itemname AND pdate BETWEEN '2011-10-01' AND '2011-10-31' ORDER BY rate ASC LIMIT 1 )

Comment: One othe question comes to mind. Do you have an `items` table?

Comment: If yes, why do you store `itemname` and not `item_id` in this `purchases` table? For preformance reasons it's always better to have smaller foreign keys (which `itemname` is or acts as, in this table).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5492/discussion-between-ypercube-and-arvind)

Comment: To answer your Postgres question, yes, I'd expect to run as is in PostgreSQL. If it needs modification, it may be on the calculations. Casting is done differently I think in Postgres, if you need casting `rate` to different datatype.

Comment: But you have additional ways to write this in Postgres, it has analytic (window) functions that may perform faster.

Answer (score 2):

Here goes. It's not pretty but it works.

```
select min.itemname, 
       min.rate, 
       min.pdate, 
       max.rate, 
       max.pdate, 
       (max.rate - min.rate)/max.rate as diff 
  from (SELECT p.itemname, 
               p.rate,
               pdate 
          from purchases p, 
               (select itemname, 
                       max(rate) as rate 
                  from purchases 
                 group by itemname) max_values 
         where p.itemname = max_values.itemname 
           and p.rate = max_values.rate
       ) max, 
       (SELECT p.itemname, 
               p.rate,
               pdate 
          from purchases p, 
               (select itemname, 
                       min(rate) as rate 
                  from purchases 
                 group by itemname) min_values 
         where p.itemname = min_values.itemname 
           and p.rate = min_values.rate
       ) min 
  where max.itemname = min.itemname;
```

Comment: Yes, this is if you have multiple dates with same max or min rate and you want all of them shown. In fact, if there are for example, 3 dates with max rate and 2 dates with min rate, all 6 combinations will be shown. +1 (despite that you use `WHERE` and not `JOIN`)

Comment: i tried the above query. It shows multiple items for Ex. ToeNailClipper is shown twice and PaperClips are displayed 4 times. infact it seems to show all records of the testdata.

Comment: @ypercube: will the query run on PostgreSql, because there is a change of DB soon.

Comment: As @ypercube says, this displays all data for those dates, that might not be what you need, then his answer is better. Also, I prefer to do "normal" joins with just , and WHERE and do LEFT OUTER JOIN with JOIN syntax, that's just my preferences :)

Comment: OK, but there are cases when you can't do that, like `a LEFT JOIN (b JOIN c)` without subqueries.